# How keep connected to a Bluetooth device with Raspbian

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have just connected my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) with bluetooth speakers (Creative D80) and they working "quite" fine.

The only issue I have is whenever I play a sound using mpg321 through a Python command, it takes a while to actually start playing something (time the Raspbian takes to establish a connection to the device).

Here you can see my code:

from os import system

```
def play(file):

    statement = 'sudo -u pi mpg321 -g 5 -q -a bluetooth sound/' + file
    system(statement)
```

Is there a way to force Raspbian to keep the connection alive all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the bluez-tools package - `sudo apt-get install bluez-tools`
2. Open the rc.local file - `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
3. Insert this command before the "exit 0" statement - `bt-audio -c MAC ID`
4. Restart your Raspberry Pi - `sudo reboot`

Comment: having the same problem but the solution does not work for me :(
are there any other options?